# Convert Json format for Nvd3 chart Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, nvd3.js

I have data like this:

```
data2 = [
        {
            "earnings_type": "C",
            "payment_date": "Jan",
            "amount": 10
        },
        {
            "earnings_type": "C",
            "payment_date": "Jan",
            "amount": 10
        }, {
            "earnings_type": "E",
           "payment_date": "Jan",
            "amount": 10
        },
    ]
```

I need to convert it to this

```
data2 = [
        {
            "key": "C", 
            "values":
            [
                {
                    "label": "15-01-2017", 
                    "value": 20 
                },
                {
                    "label": "17-02-2017",
                    "value": 16
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "key": "E",  
            "values": [
                {
                    "label": "15-01-2017",
                    "value": 15
                }
            ]
        }
        ];
```

What I need to do is go through data find all the items where the earnings_type is C and make that the key and put the values below it. Then do the same for all the items where the earnings_type is A.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the data coming from AWS api gateway. I have taken the first Json data and converted it to an array which I am using else where. But now I need to convert that array back to the second json data structure shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Array.prototype.reduce. Not sure how you'll turn payment_date into label though as the sample data has a month name for payment_date but a full date for label. If you need to use the midpoint of the month, I'm sure you can figure out how to do that based on the code below.

```
const origData = [
  {
    earnings_type: "C",
    payment_date: "Jan",
    amount: 10
  },
  {
    earnings_type: "C",
    payment_date: "Jan",
    amount: 10
  },
  {
    earnings_type: "E",
    payment_date: "Jan",
    amount: 10
  }
];

const newData = origData.reduce((result, origDataPoint) => {
  const matchingDataPoint = result.find(
    datapoint => datapoint.key === origDataPoint.earnings_type
  );
  if (!matchingDataPoint) {
    result.push({
      key: origDataPoint.earnings_type,
      values: [
        {
          label: origDataPoint.payment_date,
          value: origDataPoint.amount
        }
      ]
    });
  } else {
    matchingDataPoint.values.push({
      label: origDataPoint.payment_date,
      value: origDataPoint.amount
    });
  }
  return result;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am going to try and implement your solution now. I am sorry the data in the example is misleading. I do not need to turn the month name in a full date.I typed it like that quickly.

Comment: I implemented this solution and it works perfectly. Thanks very much.